# How to use ArrayDeque to set data to the RecyclerView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, deque, arraydeque

I have been working on a music application. In play queue I need to add data to both ends (Play next, Play later)
for that I used Array Deque and inside RecyclerView Adapter I tried to use array deque itself, but I get an error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.njz.muzic, PID: 19333
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 1(offset:1).state:2 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{5260e VFED..... ......ID 0,144-720,1520 #7f090179 app:id/nextinQueueRecyclerView}, adapter:com.njz.muzic.Adapter.NextInQueueAdapter@9da82f, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@fb91e3c, context:com.njz.muzic.PlayQueueActivity@bad4178
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6183)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23753)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1855)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23753)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23753)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23753)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23753)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23753)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1062)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23753)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3679)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3139)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9065)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:999)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:797)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:732)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:984)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8019)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

**This is my Adapter class**

```
public class NextInQueueAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NextInQueueAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Context context;
private ArrayDeque<String[]> arrayDeque;

public NextInQueueAdapter(ArrayDeque<String[]> arrayDeque, Context context) {
    this.arrayDeque = arrayDeque;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setArrayDeque(ArrayDeque<String[]> arrayDeque) {
    this.arrayDeque = arrayDeque;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.nextinqueueitem, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String[] pop = arrayDeque.pop();
    holder.id = pop[0];
    holder.artistName.setText(pop[1]);
    holder.songName.setText(pop[2]);
    Glide.with(context).load(pop[3]).into(holder.albumArtwork);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayDeque.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView artistName, songName;
    ImageView albumArtwork;
    String id;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        artistName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nextinqueueSongArtistNametv);
        songName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nextinqueueSongNametv);
        albumArtwork = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nextInQueueArtworkimage);
    }
}
```

}

**This is Activity that has RecycleView**

```
public class PlayQueueActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_queue);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.nextinQueueRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
    NextInQueueAdapter nextInQueueAdapter = new NextInQueueAdapter(HomeActivity.playqueue, this);
    nextInQueueAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(nextInQueueAdapter);
    findViewById(R.id.nextinqueuebackbutton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
}
```

}

*When I open PlayQueueActivity when ArrayDeque is empty it opens as there's no data but if I add data and opens it crashes the app*

Any help will be appreciated or am I trying to do something impossible ?
If so how am I to achieve it with any possible way ?

Thank You !

Comment: Problem is `arrayDeque.pop()` it will remove item. Why r you using `ArrayDeque`? Its not a suitable data Structure for `ListView` .  Use some type of `List` instead probably `ArrayList` .

Comment: I want to add data to both ends like **AddFirst, AddLast**  when user press play next  song should be added to top of the list and when he clicks play Later song should be added to the end of the list and show song list in Activity. Is there any suitable List I can use to achieve that ? Thanks !